# AccessControlException when opening Tomcat 7's admin console

Tags: tomcat7

when iam just opening the admin console of tomcat 7.0 by this url, iam getting below exception

```
http://localhost:8085/

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.jasper")
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.<init>(JspServletWrapper.java:120)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

Please can anyone suggest how to resolve the above issue.

Comment: You should describe exactly which version of Tomcat you are using, how you installed it and on which operating system it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run with a security manager or restore the default set of permissions ($CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy in a standard install). A default Tomcat install will work wth or without a security manager.

Comment: how can run with default properties. I mean, where do i have to change and what should need to change, to run tomcat with default properties

Comment: Copy catalina.policy from a clean install

Answer (score 1):

Change the permissions to your webapp in the file  /etc/tomcat6/policy.d/04webapps.policy

Add this->

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/<name of your webapp>/-" {
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps!